# Why can't I access Nike Plus

Tags: wine

Every time I download Nike Plus it just sits in my download box, Why doesn't my Nike+ download automatically

Answer (score 3):

Well if you're having problems downloading the Nike Plus Application then you could try downloading it with a different browser. Or if you're really desperate and its the Nike Plus Connect Software (Your Description isn't entirely accurate) try typing or copying this into your terminal:

```
wget http://nikerunning.nike.com/nikeplus/connect/installers/windows/Nike+Connect_Installer.exe
```

If on the other hand the software isn't running then you'll need WINE which should be available in the Software Centre, it allows you to run Windows software as I can't see a Linux version on their site.